# Additional records from db on mouseover on gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Here I have got a problem while designing the asp.net vb.net online Bus reservation system.
  Well, I'm trying to fetch the bus availability information from DB and show it in the gridview like this: "http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SelectBus.aspx?fromCityId=241&toCityId=122&doj=20-Dec-2014&busType=Any&opId=0". 
               Now, If you see the above link if you just hover the mouse on "Depart" there is a list will raise and in that list there is an additional information displayed means from one city how many Boarding points are there and Boarding timings also showing.
                         So, I have been trying to get the list like redbus.in, But no luck.

So, I also have done but unable to get the whole records. I'm just able to get only one record. Kindly see my code please put me in right way to find the solution.
 Here is my code:

Protected Sub gvEmployee_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvEmployee.RowDataBound

```
    '' BIND DATA WITH EACH ROW.
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim sDetails As String = "<span><h3>Boarding point And Droping point</h3></span>"
        Dim sdrEmpDet As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader( _
            "SELECT EmpID, BRpoint, BRTime,DRpoint,DRTime FROM Busdetails " & _
                "WHERE EmpID = " & e.Row.DataItem("EmpID").ToString)
        While sdrEmpDet.Read



            sDetails = sDetails & "<p><strong>Bus Code: </strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" & _
                e.Row.DataItem("EmpID").ToString & "</p>"
            sDetails = sDetails & "<p><strong>Boarding Point: </strong></br></br>" & _
                sdrEmpDet.Item("BRpoint") & "</p>"
            sDetails = sDetails & "<p><strong> </strong></br>" & sdrEmpDet.Item("BRTime") & "</p>"

            sDetails = sDetails & "<p><strong>Dropping Point </strong></br>" & sdrEmpDet.Item("DRpoint") & "</p>"
            sDetails = sDetails & "<p><strong>Dropping Time </strong></br>" & sdrEmpDet.Item("DRTime") & "</p>"
            sDetails = sDetails & "<a href=VB.aspx?id=" & e.Row.DataItem("EmpID").ToString & _
                " title=more info>See more>></a>"

            ' BIND MOUSE EVENT (TO CALL JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION), WITH EACH ROW OF THE GRID.
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "MouseEvents(this, event, '" & sDetails & "')")

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "MouseEvents(this, event, '" & e.Row.DataItem("EmpID").ToString & "')")
        End While
        sdrEmpDet.Close() : sdrEmpDet = Nothing

    End If
```

Comment: i am little confused in your select query.
"WHERE EmpID = " & e.Row.DataItem("EmpID").ToString)"
how can check with a empID (I think it is employeeID) ?
try to filter with BusID or TripID as based on your table design.

Comment: Musthaan Thank you for your reply, as of your suggestion my Busid or tripID, I have just written as EmpID for consideration, It is no where ceating any problem.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve this, your particular problem is that you need to add your mouseover event **after** the close of your while loop.

Comment: Shibby, Thank you for your agile reply. If you have any better Idea where I can achieve the above mentioned task then I would be happy. Thank you again